# In settings menu "Background" entry appears rather than "Appearance"

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.04, settings

[image]

[image]

"Appearance" still appears in the dash but opening it only opens system settings. I have a feeling this problem is related to this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285156/dash-wont-change-color-with-background-and-desktop-is-white-no-matter-what-i-cha)

Comment: You wouldn't happened to have installed GNOME 3.8 from the PPA by any chance, would you?

Comment: would that cause this?

Comment: Yes. And the dual `Online Accounts` entries.

Comment: Thank you. This solved both this problem and the problem this question is linked too. The other question has a bounty of 100 rep and if you post that answer here and on the other question I will gladly accept it

Comment: I am reluctant to answer the other question, as I don't know how/why having the GNOME 3 PPA installed would cause the background to be white. The chosen wallpaper should still get displayed.

Comment: I feel the same way but regardless, you solved my problem. And while it is very noble of you to opt not to accept the points it would make me feel better if you did. You have no idea. This is a huge weight off my shoulders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a GNOME PPA enabled, which installs a default build of GNOME without the Ubuntu patches, which includes the changes to the Background settings, to add the Unity related options, and which renames it to `Appearance`.

This is also the reason you have two different `Online Accounts` items in your `System Settings`.